# Can I trigger the ci of the git submodule?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a main project A and a git submodule B. I want to trigger the ci process of B in the gitlab-ci process of A, and then obtain the product of B, such as dist, and copy it to the project manager of A. How can I achieve this. I tried configuring GIT_ SUBMODULE_ StratEGY and trigger_ Job but failed.

```
variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

stages:
  - sub
  - build
  - deploy
  - cleanup
  - test

trigger_job:
   stage: sub
   trigger:
     include:
       - local: B/.gitlab-ci.yml
     strategy: depend
```

[image]